# what is this dialog called that appears in the center of the screen?

Tags: macos, dialog, alert

when using either Xcode or Magnet from the app store, occasionally a dialog like this appears:
[image: the dialog I am talking about]

When using magnet, this dialog appears when the window forces a specific width and cannot change the size.

in Xcode this dialog appears when the build fails or succeeds.

it appears in the center of the screen, near where the volume change notification appears.

I cannot click or interact with it

**what is this dialog called?** and **how can I make one?**

I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Can you add some context both on how you trigger this and also visually (by showing also parts of what is outside the dialog)?

Comment: Can you also add the macOS version?

Comment: I've used Magnet before and that dialog just pops up when you're trying to make a window "too narrow."  It's just a regular dialog with some custom opacity, coloring, and framing.

Comment: I edited the question to explain when it appears and how to reproduce it.